# User permmissions Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, permissions

I did not create this website and i am new to Ruby On Rails.

I have a form on my home page that wont allow members to post from it. If an admin logs in and uses it. it works great.

I am in need of information on where to look for the right permissions to i can edit them.

here is the info on the form. and other files that i think are important

Controller: (this is where it stops when in member account)

```
  def ezpost
    type = params[:post].delete(:type)
    Resque.enqueue(UserPoster, params[:post])
    redirect_to :controller => "#{type}s", :action => 'show', :id => 1, :load => params[:post]
  end
```

Controller Trucks

```
  def show 
    if params[:truck]
      params[:truck][:origin] = Location.to_point(params[:truck][:origin]) unless params[:truck][:origin].blank?
      params[:truck][:dest] = Location.to_point(params[:truck][:dest]) unless params[:truck][:dest].blank?
      @truck = Truck.new(params[:truck])
      @truck.updated_at = Time.now
      @truck.id = -1
      authorize! :show, @truck
      flash.keep[:notice] = 'Please be aware that it could take up to 5 minutes for your truck to appear in search results.'
    elsif params[:load]
      params[:load][:origin] = Location.to_point(params[:load][:origin])  unless params[:load][:origin].blank?
      params[:load][:dest] = Location.to_point(params[:load][:dest]) unless params[:load][:dest].blank?
      @truck = Truck.new(params[:load])
      @truck.updated_at = Time.now
      @truck.id = -1
      authorize! :show, @truck
      flash.keep[:notice] = 'Please be aware that it could take up to 5 minutes for your truck to appear in search results.'
    else
      @truck = Truck.find(params[:id])
      authorize! :show, @truck
    end
  end
```

here is Log file on submit of this for for member

```
Started POST "/users/ezpost?method=get" for 108.235.52.160 at 2014-04-17 13:05:44 -0500
2014-04-17 13:05:44 INFO -- Processing by UsersController#ezpost as HTML
2014-04-17 13:05:44 INFO --   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"â", "authenticity_token"=>"gYb9m7e2FcDgLVION6ryPzBrkAZApkyTeZJlu6n7Z4s=", "post"=>{"user_id"=>"12097", "origin"=>"joplin, mo", "dest"=>"", "type"=>"truck", "equipment_id"=>"1", "available"=>"2014-04-17", "expiration"=>"2014-04-21", "comments"=>"Posted From LoadMax EZ-Post Form"}, "commit"=>"Post", "method"=>"get"}
2014-04-17 13:05:44 INFO -- Redirected to http://www.loadmax.com/
2014-04-17 13:05:44 INFO -- Completed 302 Found in 31ms (ActiveRecord: 2.7ms)
2014-04-17 13:05:44 INFO -- 

Started GET "/" for 108.235.52.160 at 2014-04-17 13:05:44 -0500
2014-04-17 13:05:44 INFO -- Processing by InfoController#index as HTML
2014-04-17 13:05:44 INFO -- Redirected to http://www.loadmax.com/info/12097/home
2014-04-17 13:05:44 INFO -- Completed 302 Found in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.8ms)
2014-04-17 13:05:44 INFO --
```

here is the Log File for a Admin submitting same form

```
2014-04-17 13:02:55 INFO --   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"â", "authenticity_token"=>"BphP7bziNEqOCZWT3XzTEutRXZgDInzRjluJ6FamLlI=", "post"=>{"user_id"=>"11488", "origin"=>"joplin, mo", "dest"=>"", "type"=>"truck", "equipment_id"=>"1", "available"=>"2014-04-17", "expiration"=>"2014-04-21", "comments"=>"Posted From LoadMax EZ-Post Form"}, "commit"=>"Post", "method"=>"get"}
2014-04-17 13:02:55 INFO -- Redirected to http://loadmax.com/trucks/1?load%5Bavailable%5D=2014-04-17&load%5Bcomments%5D=Posted+From+LoadMax+EZ-Post+Form&load%5Bdest%5D=&load%5Bequipment_id%5D=1&load%5Bexpiration%5D=2014-04-21&load%5Borigin%5D=joplin%2C+mo&load%5Buser_id%5D=11488
2014-04-17 13:02:55 INFO -- Completed 302 Found in 29ms (ActiveRecord: 1.6ms)
2014-04-17 13:02:55 INFO -- 
Started GET "/trucks/1?load%5Bavailable%5D=2014-04-17&load%5Bcomments%5D=Posted+From+LoadMax+EZ-Post+Form&load%5Bdest%5D=&load%5Bequipment_id%5D=1&load%5Bexpiration%5D=2014-04-21&load%5Borigin%5D=joplin%2C+mo&load%5Buser_id%5D=11488" for 108.235.52.160 at 2014-04-17 13:02:55 -0500
2014-04-17 13:02:55 INFO -- Processing by TrucksController#show as HTML
2014-04-17 13:02:55 INFO --   Parameters: {"load"=>{"available"=>"2014-04-17", "comments"=>"Posted From LoadMax EZ-Post Form", "dest"=>"", "equipment_id"=>"1", "expiration"=>"2014-04-21", "origin"=>"joplin, mo", "user_id"=>"11488"}, "id"=>"1"}
2014-04-17 13:02:55 INFO --   Rendered trucks/show.html.haml within layouts/application (22.9ms)
```

here is my Controller_macro in spec

```
module ControllerMacros
  def login_as_full
    account_subscription "full_subscription"
  end
  def login_as_free
    account_subscription "free_subscription"
  end
  def login_as_admin
    account_subscription "admin_subscription"
  end
  def login_as_acct_mgr
    account_subscription "acct_mgr_subscription"
  end
  def login_as_comp_mgr
    account_subscription "full_subscription", "company_manager"
  end

  private

  def account_subscription(subscription_type, user_type="user")
    @company = FactoryGirl.create(:company)
    @subscription = FactoryGirl.create(subscription_type.to_sym, company_id: @company.id)
    @user = FactoryGirl.create(user_type.to_sym, company_id: @company.id)
    sign_in @user
  end
end
```

Teirs.yml file... Teir 1 and 3 are the ones i am working with

```
# Fixture file to import all subscription tiers into database. See db/seeds.rb

admin: 
  desc: "null"
  id: 1
  name: "admin"
account_manager: 
  desc: "null"
  id: 2
  name: "account_manager" 
normal: 
  desc: "null"
  id: 3
  name: "normal"
free: 
  desc: "null" 
  id: 4
  name: "free"
mobile: 
  desc: "null"
  id: 5
  name: "mobile"
demo:
  desc: "null"
  id: 6
  name: "demo"
```

spec/factories/Subscription.rb

require 'factory_girl'

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :subscription do
  end

  factory :admin_subscription, parent: :subscription do
    tier_id             '1'
  end

  factory :acct_mgr_subscription, parent: :subscription do
    tier_id             '2'
  end

  factory :full_subscription, parent: :subscription do
    tier_id             '3'
  end

  factory :free_subscription, parent: :subscription do
    tier_id             '4'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previous programmer is using the gem cancan. You can tell by the `authorize!` statement.

```
authorize! :show, @truck
```

You can find the documentation here.
https://github.com/ryanb/cancan

In particular, it should be the `app/models/ability.rb` file. Depending on the previous set permission, you can modify it to allow edits on `Truck`.

Here is some more info.
https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/defining-abilities

Comment: Thank you VERY VERY much. I am still learning ruby and been looking thru these files. guess i didnt see this one because it  didnt correspond with a controller or view

Comment: It was acually ezpost that i had to add... but thanks for pointing me to the permissions file